# How to use fontawesome with fixed width?

Tags: width, fontawesome, textwidth

I'm using XeLaTeX and `fontawesome` package.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\section{\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\section{\faBook \textbackslash faBook}

\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBook \textbackslash publications

\end{document}
```

And this is the cropped result:

[image: example]

How can I obtain a fixed width with `fontawesome` icons? I don't want to manually adjust the space each time and the solution should work both in simple text and inside sections.

Edit: If I could choose between ragged left, right or centered would be perfect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, a command such as `\faBook` gets translated into `\faicon{book}`, with a predefined table; so what we want to change is the action of `\faicon`, which by default is

```
\newcommand*{\faicon}[1]{{\csname faicon@#1\endcsname}}
```

Just change this into

```
\renewcommand*{\faicon}[1]{{\makebox[1.5em][c]{\csname faicon@#1\endcsname}}
```

I'm afraid you will have to adjust visually the fixed width depending on the widest icon you need to print.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\renewcommand*{\faicon}[1]{\makebox[1.5em][c]{\csname faicon@#1\endcsname}}

\begin{document}

\section{\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\section{\faBook \textbackslash faBook}

\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBook \textbackslash publications

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add an optional alignment argument to all `fontawesome` commands. The `\ignorespaces` makes the commands ignore a following space even if present, so

```
\faBook Publications
\faBook[r] Publications
```

are the same as

```
\faBook Publications
\faBook[r]Publications
```

and you don't need to worry about spaces if you add the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\faicon}{mO{c}}{%
  \makebox[1.5em][#2]{\csname faicon@#1\endcsname}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\section{\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\section{\faBook \textbackslash faBook}

\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBook \textbackslash publications

\noindent
\vrule\faGraduationCap\vrule\faBook\vrule \\
\vrule\faGraduationCap[l]\vrule\faBook[l]\vrule \\
\vrule\faGraduationCap[r]\vrule\faBook[r]\vrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The result is the same of [Tobi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432466/89662) but yours is cleaner and uses the builtin command faicon. However I improved the Tobi's solution in my answer to take the alignment as an optional argument. I tried to do the same thing with yours but without success. There is a way to add the alignment as optional argument using your solution (without redefining each icon)?

Comment: @gvgramazio Quite easy. `;-)`

Answer (score 6):

You could wrap the icons in a box of a fixed width. Furthermore I‘d make a new macro for this, to easily change the width later for example:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand{\faBox}[1]{%
   \makebox[1.25em][l]{%
      \csname fa#1\endcsname   
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\section{\faBook \textbackslash faBook}

\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBook \textbackslash publications

\section{\faBox{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\section{\faBox{Book} \textbackslash faBook}

\faBox{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBox{Book} \textbackslash publications

\end{document}
```

The first argument of `\makebox` is the width, the second (optional) one the alignment in the box (`c`enter = default, `l`eft or `r`ight) and the last one is the content of the box, which actually could be wider than the box itself. In this case it‘ll overflow the box.

`\csname` and `\endcsname` can be used to “construct” a macro name an call it.

Comment: I cannot edit you anwer because there are too few characters to edit: please change the brackets around `1em` in the `makebox` call.

Comment: @gvgramazio: Sorry, it was late yesterday ;-) I fixed my code …

Answer (score 1):

I did an answer only because it has an additional feature. However, for an obviously reason, I will not mark my answer as an accepted one.

In the following an improvement of [Tobi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432466/89662). I added as optional argument the alignment inside the box.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand{\faBox}[2][c]{%
   \makebox[1em][#1]{%
      \csname fa#2\endcsname
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{No \textbackslash fabox}

\subsection*{\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\subsection*{\faBook \textbackslash faBook}

\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBook \textbackslash publications

\section{Default \textbackslash fabox}

\subsection*{\faBox{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\subsection*{\faBox{Book} \textbackslash faBook}

\faBox{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBox{Book} \textbackslash publications

\section{Left \textbackslash fabox}

\subsection*{\faBox[l]{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\subsection*{\faBox[l]{Book} \textbackslash faBook}

\faBox[l]{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBox[l]{Book} \textbackslash publications

\section{Center (default) \textbackslash box}

\subsection*{\faBox[c]{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\subsection*{\faBox[c]{Book} \textbackslash faBook}

\faBox[c]{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBox[c]{Book} \textbackslash publications

\section{Right \textbackslash box}

\subsection*{\faBox[r]{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\subsection*{\faBox[r]{Book} \textbackslash faBook}

\faBox[r]{GraduationCap} \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBox[r]{Book} \textbackslash publications

\end{document}
```

And this is the result.

[image: tobi]