# How to use Font Awesome 5 with fixed width

Tags: fontawesome

What I need is basically this: [How to use fontawesome with fixed width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432460/how-to-use-fontawesome-with-fixed-width) but using the new `fontawesome5` package.

There, they redefine `\faicon` command but it has been changed in the new version. `Fontawesome5` defines `\faIcon` as:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\faIcon{s O{\str_use:N\l_fontawesome_style_str} m}{
  \fontawesome_use_icon:nn{#2}{#3\IfBooleanT{#1}{-alt}}
}
```

So, theoretically, this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand\faIcon{s O{\str_use:N\l_fontawesome_style_str} m}{
  \makebox[1.5em][c] \fontawesome_use_icon:nn{#2}{#3\IfBooleanT{#1}{-alt}}
}

\begin{document}

\section{\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\section{\faBook \textbackslash faBook}

\faGraduationCap \textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBook \textbackslash publications

\end{document}
```

But it's not... so what is wrong?

Comment: fontawesome5 handles this differently. You would need to redefine an internal command. Better make a feature request to the author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the original commands to do this you would have to redefine internal commands. Better make a feature request for a suitable style.

But beside this you can define your own command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\fixfaIcon{ m s}{\makebox[1.5em][c]{\IfBooleanTF{#2}{\csname fa#1\endcsname*}{\csname fa#1\endcsname}}}

\begin{document}

\section{\fixfaIcon{GraduationCap}\textbackslash faGraduationCap}
\section{\fixfaIcon{Book}\textbackslash faBook}

\fixfaIcon{GraduationCap}\textbackslash faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\fixfaIcon{Book}\textbackslash publications
\fixfaIcon{File}*  \fixfaIcon{File}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work with alternative icons, those that end with *.

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: [solid] and [regular] arguments functionality are missing. Adding an optional argument works: `\NewDocumentCommand\fixfaIcon{msO{solid}}{\makebox[1.5em][c]{\IfBooleanTF{#2}{\csname fa#1\endcsname*}{\csname fa#1\endcsname}[#3]}}`

Comment: Another problem are icons with digits in their name and fixing them is more difficult. Anyway I would recommend using the `\faIcon{book}` syntax instead of  `\faBook` for this.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with `fontawesome5` version 5.4.1, released on 2018-10-13, you can pass the option `fixed` to `fontawesome5` to get all icons in fixed-width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\section{\faGraduationCap \string\faGraduationCap}
\section{\faBook \string\faBook}

\faGraduationCap \string\faGraduationCap\par\noindent
\faBook \string\faBook

\end{document}
```

[image]